# Building a C++ project with two different configurations in the same solution configuration

Tags: visual-studio, visual-c++, msbuild, visual-studio-2019

We have multiple C++ projects in our solution that all support different configurations (I'll omit some uninteresting ones here):

1. Shared (Debug, DebugMD)
2. A (DebugMD)
3. B (Debug)

Both `A` and `B` depend on `Shared`, but `A` depends on `Shared (DebugMD)` and `B` depends on `Shared (Debug)`.

We have one solution configuration `Debug`, that builds:

- Shared (Debug)
- A (DebugMD)
- B (Debug)

However, this configuration breaks `A`, because we don't build `Shared (DebugMD)`. Is it possible to build `Shared (Debug)` and `Shared (DebugMD)` within the same solution configuration (without batch builds)?

---

I've read [Can I build multiple configurations of a project within one solution configuration?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13768967/can-i-build-multiple-configurations-of-a-project-within-one-solution-configurati), but this only seems to work for .net projects (or at least I couldn't get it working for .vcxprojs).

Comment: Have you considered a Batch Build ( Build menu->Batch Build?

Comment: @JohnCz Batch build isn't an option. I don't want to have to batch build for the solution to build correctly.

Comment: The principle in the link you mention (add a custom target which builds the project with another configuration) is the same for C++, you just need a different way to invoke the target. There are quite a lot of possibilities, some answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13727351/what-happened-to-beforebuild-and-other-targets-in-vs2012